# PHP jQuery mysql upload multiple $_REQUEST

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<?php
    $field_values_array = $_REQUEST['field_name'];
    foreach($field_values_array as $value){

        echo $value;
    }
    ?>
```

The code above is my PHP loop to insert from the form to the database, my problem now is that one of the input names is `field_name`, and then this name goes into the loop. I need to loop 3 $_REQUEST as following: field_name, field_name1, field_name2.

How can I do this? I cannot use `$field_values_array = array($_REQUEST["field_name"],$_REQUEST["field_name1"],$_REQUEST["field_name2"])‌​;` since it gives me the error code `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING)`

Comment: First check is all values set for `$_REQUEST['field_name']`. If `$_REQUEST` have 3 values then only you can loop $_REQUEST.

Comment: But then it request so much more, how can I change this?

Comment: When you are executing this code? Is the parameter `field_name` is set from URL?

Comment: I get "SUBMIT" there too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  $field_values_array = array('$_REQUEST["field_name"]'=>$_REQUEST["field_name"],'$_REQUEST["field_name1"]'=>$_REQUEST["field_name1"],'$_REQUEST["field_name2"]'=>$_REQUEST["field_name2"])‌​;
```

$i =1; foreach($field_values_array as $value){

```
    echo $value['field_name'.$i];
```

$i++;  }
?>